# ASP.NET built in validation attribute to specify a min or max value?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

How can I specify that a value has a certin minimum **OR** maximum?

I can do range such as:

```
[Range(0 , 3)]
public int start { get; set; }
```

But that specifies its upper **and** lower bounds. How can I just check if my value is positive ie greater than 0?

Here is my current domain model:

```
public class Block
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value for block id.")]
    public int blockID { get; set; }

    //Start Account code
    [Range(0 , 3)]
    public int start { get; set; }

    //End Account code
    public int end { get; set; }

    //Size of the block space
    public int blockSize { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Customer customer { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What about `[Range(1 , 1000)]`?

Comment: Yes but I want to know for the case  (x > 0)  that is for the case (0< x <1000 )

Comment: unclear, with your comment

Comment: Maybe you mean that you want one error message if x less than 1 and another if x greater than 1000?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the min and max value as

```
[Range(1 , 999)]
```

Comment: Ling the Op wants the range to be greater than 0 and less than 1000. Your answer should be [Range(1, 999)]. Cheers